git fatal: protocol error: bad line length 173
I'm trying to push my code to GitHub, however I receive the following error:
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 173

Full log:
$ git push --set-upstream origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://user@github.com': 
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 173
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repository.git'
Enumerating objects: 32, done.
Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.

I found the following SO question, but there they tried to connect to a git server that they own.
Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab
How can I solve it when pushing to GitHub?
I'm using Linux.

send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet is a much more important line here. How long does this run before it returns that?

Git waits about 3 seconds before throwing the errors.

It might be caused by a compression issue, try disabling it:
git config --global core.compression 0

More in the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/#Documentation/git-config.txt-corecompression

Thank you Lars, unfortunately, the issue still persits

Because your download cache is too high, change it to default:
git config --global http.postBuffer 1M


More in the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/#Documentation/git-config.txt-httppostBuffer

